# TypeScript reuse type with dynamic argument

Tags: typescript, types

Please, tell me, can I do this with ts?
I have next source code:

```
interface FormStore<T> {
  type: T;
}

interface Form<T> extends FormStore<T> {
  email: T;
  phone: T;
  password: T;
}

interface FormState<R> {
  form: Form<string>;
  validate: Form<boolean>;
}
```

I want to reuse type `FormState<R>` and create new with argument. It something looks like replace `Form` on `R`:

```
// This example doesn't work, just only for example
interface FormState<R> {
  form: R<string>;
  validate: R<boolean>;
}

// another file
FormState<CustomForm>
```

Comment: `R<string>` it will not work. TS does not support higher kinded types

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes, and because I ask: how do it? I showed plan, implementation can be any

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/we07BW) work for you?  Without true higher-kinded types in TypeScript, you can only simulate them via something like a registry.  Anytime you create a new type you want to use like this, you need to add it to the registry.  If that approach works for you I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the code to show failed use cases.

Comment: @jcalz  it is the best way for me for now.

Comment: @reznikovkg When you say "for now" does that mean you're waiting for other suggestions?  I'm trying to decide whether to write up an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your original declaration, this is the best I can do for now. If you don't make set a default type parameter for `FormStore` & `Form`, you will have to explicitly use `type FormStateF = FormState<Form<unknown>>;`, which is awkward.

```
interface FormStore<T = unknown> {
  type: T;
}

interface Form<T = unknown> extends FormStore<T> {
  email: T;
  phone: T;
  password: T;
}

interface FormState<R> {
  form: { [x in keyof R]: string };
  validate: { [x in keyof R]: boolean };
}

type FormStateF = FormState<Form>;
```